Speeding up python loop
I created a for loop that takes a value from one column, and looks ahead if that value has been exceeded either one or two times in later data. The code works, but as the dataset it runs on is very large, the code gets really slow. I suspect particularly because each iteration it counts how many times a value is exceeded (over about 500k rows). Is there a way to speed it up?
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'index': [0,1,2,3,4], 'Time': ['2022-01-01','2022-01-02','2022-01-03','2022-01-04','2022-01-05'], 'A':[234,456,323,576,234], 'B': [0,1,0,1,0], 'B.v': [0,234,0,323,0], 'in' : [0,0,0,0,0], 'out':[0,0,0,0,0]})


def calc(df1):

    df2 = pd.DataFrame(df1[df1['B'] ==  1])

    for x in range(len(df2)):
        index = df2.iloc[x, df2.columns.get_loc('index')]
        tvalue = df2.iloc[x, df2.columns.get_loc('A')]
        pointvalue = df2.iloc[x, df2.columns.get_loc('B.v')]
        postrates = df1['A'].values[range(index,len(df1))]

        if sum(pointvalue > postrates) == 1:
            df1.iloc[index, df1.columns.get_loc('in')] = 1
        if sum(pointvalue > postrates) >= 2:
            df1.iloc[index, df1.columns.get_loc('in')] = 2

        if sum(tvalue < postrates) == 1:
            df1.iloc[index, df1.columns.get_loc('out')] = 1
        if sum(tvalue < postrates) >= 2:
            df1.iloc[index, df1.columns.get_loc('out')] = 2
    return df1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(calc(df1))


Why don't you simply loop once over the data and bucket the occurrences, then loop over the buckets to find the ones you wanted?

I'm not sure I understand your comment, but I made it this way because 'postrates' shifts over time, as it is dependent on the index of 'B.v'. basically you only want to compare to future data.

Note that using sum on Numpy array is inefficient. Using lists is clearly sub-optimal due to objects. Using iloc is known to be slow though the sum are certainly the issue. On top of that, when you type sum(tvalue < postrates) twice, then it is computed twice which is inefficient. Be aware that CPython is an interpreter so it optimize nearly nothing and it is up to you not to recompute things many times.

I'd use numba to speed up the computation (with added short-circuit: when the two sums are already >= 2 there's no need to count further):
import numba


@numba.njit(parallel=True)
def calc_in_out(A, B, Bv, out_in, out_out):
    for idx in numba.prange(len(B)):
        val_b = B[idx]

        if val_b != 1:
            continue

        val_a = A[idx]
        val_Bv = Bv[idx]

        s1, s2 = 0, 0
        for idx2 in range(idx, len(B)):
            s1 += val_Bv > A[idx2]
            s2 += val_a < A[idx2]

            # no need to count further:
            if s1 >= 2 and s2 >= 2:
                break

        if s1 == 1:
            out_in[idx] = 1
        elif s1 >= 2:
            out_in[idx] = 2

        if s2 == 1:
            out_out[idx] = 1
        elif s2 >= 2:
            out_out[idx] = 2


Benchmark:
from timeit import timeit

import numba
import numpy as np


@numba.njit(parallel=True)
def calc_in_out(A, B, Bv, out_in, out_out):
    for idx in numba.prange(len(B)):
        val_b = B[idx]

        if val_b != 1:
            continue

        val_a = A[idx]
        val_Bv = Bv[idx]

        s1, s2 = 0, 0
        for idx2 in range(idx, len(B)):
            s1 += val_Bv > A[idx2]
            s2 += val_a < A[idx2]

            # no need to count further:
            if s1 >= 2 and s2 >= 2:
                break

        if s1 == 1:
            out_in[idx] = 1
        elif s1 >= 2:
            out_in[idx] = 2

        if s2 == 1:
            out_out[idx] = 1
        elif s2 >= 2:
            out_out[idx] = 2

def setup_df(N=500_000):
    return pd.DataFrame(
        {
            "Time": ["2022-01-01"] * N,
            "A": np.random.randint(10, 1000, size=N),
            "B": np.random.randint(0, 2, size=N),
            "B.v": np.random.randint(10, 1000, size=N),
            "in": [0] * N,
            "out": [0] * N,
        }
    )


def main():
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(
        {
            "index": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
            "Time": [
                "2022-01-01",
                "2022-01-02",
                "2022-01-03",
                "2022-01-04",
                "2022-01-05",
            ],
            "A": [234, 456, 323, 576, 234],
            "B": [0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
            "B.v": [0, 234, 0, 323, 0],
            "in": [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            "out": [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        }
    )

    # this will compile calc_in_out
    calc_in_out(
        df1["A"].values,
        df1["B"].values,
        df1["B.v"].values,
        df1["in"].values,
        df1["out"].values,
    )
    print(df1)

    to_run = """calc_in_out(
        df1["A"].values,
        df1["B"].values,
        df1["B.v"].values,
        df1["in"].values,
        df1["out"].values,
    )"""

    t = timeit(to_run, setup="df1=setup_df()", globals=globals(), number=1)
    print(t)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

This prints on my machine (AMD 5700x):
0.023107149987481534


Wow... great answer, Thanks! the difference in speed is incredible. I'm gonne have to apply these principles to all my butcher code
